# Nested lists of differing lengths into pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have an input file that I read from line by line into a nested list. The file has the format

```
int string float
int_1 int_2 ... int_n
```

Where each second line has a different number of integers. I read the file using

```
sim = []
with open(sim_out, 'r') as sim_file_out:
    for line in sim_file_out:
        sim.append(line.split())
```

And each line reads as a list of strings. Since these alternate, once they're in the parent list it's easy to split up with even and odd indices. The problem is that I need to take the list that contains the integer row, convert to integers and store each as an array so that I can use the arrays as indexers later. Originally I did this using

```
import numpy as np
sim_events = []
for i, j in enumerate(sim):
    sim_events.append(np.array(list(map(int, j))))
```

Which proved to be extremely slow (I iterate over anywhere between 20k and 3million lines) and took my runtime from less than a second to several minutes. I countered this using

```
import pandas as pd
odds = np.arange(1,len(sim),2)
sim = np.array(sim)
sites = sim[odds].tolist()
for ii, jj in enumerate(sites):
    sites[ii] = list(map(eval,jj))
sim_events = pd.DataFrame(sites)
```

Which brought the execution time back down to less than a second, but leaves me with a dataframe with a ton of NaN. Later, I iterate over an array of equal length, and to get each row as an array that can be used as an index I have to use

```
for i in other_array:
    step_sites = sim_events.iloc[i].dropna().values.astype(int)-1
```

Which is also very time consuming because it has to be done at every step.

Any suggestions how to get around this? I know that I can just get the values from the df and filter out the NaN, but when I do this I lose the structure of the differing length arrays and this is something that MUST be retained.

Answer (score 0):

```
sim_events = []
for i, j in enumerate(sim):
    sim_events.append(np.array(list(map(int, j))))
```

can be simplified to

```
sim_events = []
for j in sim:
    sim_events.append(np.array(j, int))
```

since you aren't using the `i` index, and `np.array` can convert strings to integers.

You can take the odd lists from `sim` with `sim[1::2]`.

Beyond that I'm having trouble visualizing the dataframe that you get/want.

Answer (score 0):

What's slowing me down is the conversion to an array at each step. Thats why my last attempt only appended a mapped list. Even removing the mapping and only appending an array is very slow for my application. But since I'm left with a nested list of strings the only way I can convert is to loop back through with

```
for ii, jj in enumerate(sites):
    sites[ii] = list(map(eval,jj))
sim_events = pd.DataFrame(sites)
```

Giving me the array like qualities that I need for indexing later. But this also leaves me with a dataframe looking like [image]

This is just an example from a df with 90k rows. I can't use `fillna` because I need them to be ints and then I run the risk of interfering with other data. So later when I want to use these rows as indexers I have to use something like

```
for i in other_array:
    step_sites = sim_events.iloc[i].dropna().values.astype(int)-1
```

Which is also very time consuming